# IE8, Flash, and the WinForms WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer-8

I have a WebBrowser control on a Form that is loading a single page with a flash control on it.  Since upgrading to IE8 it no longer works.  Every time I open my form I get a prompt to install Flash.  No matter what I choose to do from there Flash will not start, so my page is busted.  Any clues on how to get Flash to work in IE when it is running as an embedded control?

If I navigate to this page in IE8 outside my app the page works fine.

Comment: I've been able to figure this out after digging into it a bit more.  I was wrong to blame IE8, but my actual problem was when running my windows app as a 64 bit application.  Flash fails to load in this mode (I've encountered problems with COM in 64 bits before too) and that is the source of my problem.  Because of high memory usage some people need to run my app in 64 bit mode if their computer supports it.  Does anyone know how to make the WebBrowser control load the 32 bit IE control as the underlying activeX control?  Yes, I know that is a long shot on every actually working.  Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, no, there's no way to make your 64bit app host the 32bit WebBrowser control. If you were calling CoCreateInstance directly to create an out-of-process IE instance, you could try passing CLSCTX_ACTIVATE_32_BIT_SERVER.

Comment: Is the hosted page html + flash or is it primarily just flash?

Comment: There is a shell html document that hosts the flash control full screen.  The document also creates some stub methods that call into the WinForms app to send messages to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can host the Flash ActiveX control in your WinForms app directly instead of using a browser control.  We do this in our app and it works.  Has a few quirks like ESC in full-screen mode doesn't actually exit full screen, but for most part works.

There's also an API (but poorly documented) for communicating between the SWF and the WinForms app.  We haven't used it ourselves though.